# Connection cannot be made to redirector

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssas, sql-server-2012-datatools

[image]

I am trying to deploy my first SSAS project. The Sql server is on a remote machine. I'm able to RDP and ping the machine.

1. I have restarted the SQL Browser service
2. sql browser has been started with admin account
3. I've turned off the firewall
4. I have given full control to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\ASConfig folder to the user SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$etc............

After a few hours of research, I've seen that one solution to this is to give the AS user rights to that folder.

I don't have an `AS` user at all on that machine.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I deploy my first project?**

Because I've gotten no responses to this posting, I'm wondering if this might be a bug. Where can I find the documentation for exactly what is needed for deployment?

Comment: You seem to have tagged your post with "sql-server-2012-datatools" but the folder path you reference is for Analysis Services *2005*. Is that correct? If so you might be having a compatibility issue and you should be using SQL Server 2005 tools (specifically BIDS 2005) for Analysis Services 2005 development.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually what I wrote is indeed correct. That user name for data tools 2012 is sql server 2005...